# How to perform row-wise multiplication of a big.matrix in R?

Tags: r, performance, matrix, multiplication, r-bigmemory

1. Suppose `A` is an R matrix. If I want to perform row-wise multiplication with elements from a vector `vec`, I could do:

`sweep( A, 1, vec, "*" )`.

Is there a similar, but efficient way to do the same if `A` was a `big.matrix` R object?

2. My main goal is the following: I have two large matrices of dimension ~ `3500x3500` elements, `A` and `B`. I want to do the following operation:

`B %*% sweep( A, 1, vec, "*" )`.

I have to do these matrix multiplications over many iterations, but `vec` alone changes over each iteration. So I thought big.matrix/bigalgebra packages might offer convenient ways to do such matrix multiplications, but that row-wise multiplication needs to be dealt with. (I realize I can cast the `vec` entries as a diagonal big.matrix and do a full blown multiplication, but I would rather prefer dealing just with the diagonal entries like above.) Ay ideas / are there other alternative packages to do the same?

I greatly appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Would just `A * vec` speed things up? Since `vec` will loop over the rows anyway.

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail. That definitely speeds up the base R code! Thanks! For big.matrix however, I will have to do something like : `B %*% as.big.matrix( A * vec )` every time `vec` changes correct, supposing `B` is already a big.matrix? This is because `bigalgebra` package currently does not seem to offer a `*` operator like base R? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Why do you need to use `big.matrix` objects with `3500x3500`?